# Are actionscript bitmaps faster than vectors?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm working on a project which draws circles continuously at framerate and animates them around the stage and I'm running into performance issues.

I'm already converting all objects to bitmapData as soon as they become static. My question is, will converting the circles to bitmapData as soon as they are drawn increase performance? In other words, is animating say, 200 bitmaps (with transparency) faster than 200 vector circles?

Are there any drawbacks to this technique? (I'm thinking opacity problems maybe?)

If they were more complex shapes than circles would the answer be different?

Any other tips on improving performance?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you only needs what you describe there, you can set the property `cacheAsBitmap` of your DisplayObject to true.

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot about cacheAsBitmap! Havent used it in years. It helps a lot but still having some issues with more complicated shapes. What about hardware acceleration? will that help?

Comment: I don't know, but you really shouldn't worry that much. Could you tell us what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @M28 ,I would eventually like to be able to draw a tonne of simple shapes (circles & lines) and have them animate independently by size, opacity and co ordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches you might consider here:

1. **Bet on the vector renderer** by drawing your lines and circles each frame. They'll get re-rendered every time, but then that's what Flash is heavily optimized for, so it's not impossible that this could be faster than the alternatives. (Note that drawing the objects at different sizes each frame might be faster than drawing them each into a `Sprite` and changing its size.)
2. **Bet against the vector renderer** by moving bitmaps around. A simple way to do this (assuming you're drawing the shapes with AS3) would be to draw the shapes into `Bitmap` objects and then move those around. You may not be happy with the jagginess of the result. Enabling bitmap smoothing will help (but cost some performance).
   *Note:* `cacheAsBitmap` will probably not do what you want here, because cached bitmaps get redrawn when the object changes size (not sure about transparency).
3. **Bet on hardware acceleration** by using [cacheAsBitmapMatrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmapMatrix). This is only available in AIR, so it may not work for you. CABM is similar to cacheAsBitmap, but it doesn't redraw the contents as they rescale. Further, in many cases the bitmap gets handed to hardware, and thus can be rescaled on the GPU. I believe there are platforms where that doesn't work though. This is generally very fast, especially on mobile devices.
4. **Bet on AS3 bitmap handling** by blitting stuff into a stage-sized BitmapData. But note even if you do this, you'll still need to decide whether to draw shapes into your big bitmap each frame (like option 1) or draw them into individual bitmaps and blit those (transformed) into the big bitmap each frame (like option 2).

I don't think there's any way to know which option is best without experimenting. I'm almost certain that option 3 will be the best if you're using AIR and if HW acceleration works on your platform, but those may not be true. My gut instinct is that option 4 will not be terribly helpful. Blitting can be very fast when you are drawing lots of of static bitmaps onto the stage untransformed, but in this case you need to be either generating or transforming the content each frame, so my guess is that the benefit of blitting will not occur where your bottleneck is. My best guess is that option 2 will be faster than 1, but you may not be happy with the visuals.

Comment: Great answer @fenomas. Thanks a lot. I'm compiling to an exe so I guess I could use AIR and have users install the thing. Do you know if Hardware Acceleration is enabled in the flash testing environment? Should I use GPU or CPU acceleration do you think?

Comment: I'm not fully up on the details, but "CPU" should disable hardware acceleration (I always use "auto", and I think that's the recommended setting.) With that said though, after a little googling I'm really not sure of the situation with HWA on desktops. What I said about bitmaps getting scaled on the GPU might depend some on arcane things that are hard to test. (If the GPU is wholly uninvolved I'd think we might expect option 3 to perform similarly to 2..?) Also there are other kinds of HWA involved besides surfaces (bitmaps handled by HW), it's an extremely arcane subject.

Comment: Right thanks a lot. I'm doing some tests with different setups. I might report back or write a blog entry about it if I come to any conclusions. Thanks for the help fenomas :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into Blitting if you're looking for performance. It's a technique that used to be heavily used in 2D games; in Actionscript, it's implemented via the BitmapData.copyPixels() method.

It's substantially faster the displaylist in many cases; google the term "Blitting in AS3" and you'll find a lot of worthwhile data. [8bitrocket.com](http://www.8bitrocket.com/category/tutorials/tutorial-flash/) has some good tutorials for it as well.

Comment: Cheers @lunchmeat317 - I've been looking into this alright. The thing is I'm just using different coloured circles which have to change size and move around slightly. Is blitting still the best approach?

Comment: It really depends on the performance you're getting and what types of objects you're going to have on stage. Generally, though, I would say yes. There's a site that had a blit test that I was going to link, but I can't find it. If I do, I'll let you know.

Comment: I expanded a bit in an answer, but I'm leery about blitting here, since the stuff to be blitted must be drawn or transformed every frame. The benefit of blitting is that it removes overhead, but I suspect that overhead here is small compared to the cost of drawing or transforming the shapes.

Comment: @fenomas I haven't tested this thoroughly, but I believe that using copypixels() on a frame-by-frame basis on a transforming movieclip is faster than letting the vector engine do the work. However, there might be problems with positioning due to the changing size of the bounding box, which you'd have to deal with manually...

Comment: Lunch, my guess is that you're right, it's just that I think the savings will be small compared to the cost of transforms. Blitting screams for cases where you work with bitmaps that don't need to be scaled or smoothed, because then the only thing limiting you is overhead.. But my guess is that won't be the case here. Wouldn't be surprised to be wrong though! ;)

Comment: From what I understand, scaling and smoothing Bitmaps take a lot of overhead - but doing so to Vector objects does not. As such, I think it's possible to create a movieclip object based on the vector engine, without adding it to the displaylist; you then can transform the movieclip behind the scenes, but you don't have to have the Vector engine handle drawing. Again, though, I have not tested this, so take this with a brick of salt. :P

Comment: *Transforming* objects is free in any case - all transforming does is change some numbers inside the object's transform matrix. The cost comes when the object gets rendered, and even if you use a movieclip off the display list, you still use the renderer when you call BitmapData.draw() to get it into a bitmap for blitting. When I talked about overhead I meant stuff other than rendering.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of reasons you might be experiencing performance issues. It sounds like you're using the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event, which produces animation speeds subject to the frame rate.  Look into timer based animation using the `Timer` class along with `TimerEvent.TIMER`. Using a single `Timer` object to orchestrate your animation might help you achieve the performance you're looking for.

You can also try calling `updateAfterEvent()` on the event object in your event handler. I'm not sure if an Enter_Frame event can call `updateAfterEvent()`, but a `TIMER` event can.

If the vector circles themselves do not change shape, color, line width, etc. when they animate around the stage, then the process should be quite efficient. The trick is to ensure that they are not rendered each time they change position on the stage, but are only redrawn when one or more of their graphic's properties has changed.

If I had to choose one thing, I'd say you're vectors are redrawing themselves on each screen update.

Comment: Thanks @elekwent. Which process are you referring to as being more effecient? The bitmapData process? The circles only change in size position and opacity

Comment: I was referring to moving vectors around the stage as being efficient as long as the vector's graphics aren't redrawn every frame.

Comment: Thanks again @elekwent. I'm actually using the tween class to animate the circles so as far as I know they're not redrawn every frame,instead just moved around. I could try animating at lower frame rates but id like to keep the movement smooth and silky.

Comment: One correction: visual effects should always be driven from ENTER_FRAME events, not timers. The reason is that you want your code executed once and only once per screen refresh. Any more often and you waste CPU on updates the user won't see, and any less often and Flash wastes CPU redrawing the screen even though nothing's changed. Calling `updateAfterEvent` only makes matters worse - it forces flash to do more redraws per second than it would have otherwise.